# php bindParam not working with LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm connecting to my database through a PDO and I'm preparing this statement and then binding the parameter:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_name LIKE '%:mName%'");
$stmt->bindParam(':mName', $moviename);
```

It doesn't find anything in the database but if I do it like this, it works:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_name LIKE '%". $moviename . "%'");
```

This is the full code, below:

```
<?php
    function Search_movie(){
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cinema;charset=utf8', 'root');
            $moviename = 'cloud'; 

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_name LIKE '%:mName%'");
            $stmt->bindParam(':mName', $moviename); 
            var_dump($stmt);
            $stmt->execute();

            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            print "<br>";
            var_dump($data);
    } 

    Search_movie();
?>
```

Can anybody tell me why it works that way?

Comment: IT`s the way prepared statements teleport the query together that prevents the first query from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to not include the `%` in your query but in your param, as it is part of the search expression and not a "flag" of `LIKE` :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_name LIKE :mName");
$stmt->bindParam(':mName', '%' . $moviename . '%');
```

Note that you don't have to put the simple-quotes around the parameter, since PDO will be dealing with this on its own.

Comment: you cant pass '%' . $moviename . '%' to bindParam, only to bindValue